# PopupTemplate - format currency arcgis javascript api v4.x

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I am trying to format a field (Add a dollar sign in front of the field and place commas at correct locations) in ArcGIS javascript api 4.x using a popup template.  Here is the popuptemplate I have so far.  The field I would like to format as currency is "cost":

```
 var myPopup = new PopupTemplate({
            title: "MyPopup",
            content: [{
                type: "fields",
                fieldInfos: myfields,
                attributes: { cost: "$[cost]" }
            }]
        });
```

However this only displays the field name with a $ in front of it in the popup:

```
$[cost]
```

How would I actually get the value of "cost" to display?  Thanks before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FieldsContent` (`type:"fields"`), so you need to use the `format` property of the `FieldInfo`. With this you can format the number of places after comma and if you want a digit separator. In your example it could be,

```
var myPopup = new PopupTemplate({
    title: "MyPopup",
    content: [{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [
            // ... before fields
            {
            fieldName: 'cost',
            label: 'Cost $',
            format: {
                places: 2,
                digitSeparator: true
            }
        }
        // ... after fields
        ]
    }]
});
```

**EDIT**

In the case you want to add some extra format you can,

1. define an expression using Arcade,
2. add it to the popup template `expressionsInfos`,
3. and then reference in `fieldName`.

Something like this,

```
var myPopup = new PopupTemplate({
    title: "MyPopup",
    content: [{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [
            // ... before fields
            {
                fieldName: "expression/cost",
                label: 'Cost',
                format: {
                    places: 2,
                    digitSeparator: true
                }
            }
            // ... after fields
        ]
    }],
    expressionInfos: [{
        name: "cost",
        title: "Cost",
        expression: "Text($feature.cost, '$#,###.00')"
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thank you Cabesuon.  Is there a way to place the $ sign right before the number?

Comment: Thank you Cabesuon that worked perfect!  I marked your answer as accepted.  By any chance do you know how to hide a popup row?  I created this new question for that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75880377