# PopupTemplate - How to hide a row based on attribute value - ArcGIS Javascript API 4.x

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have the following PopupTemplate using arcgis javascript api 4.x

```
var myPopup = new PopupTemplate({
    title: "MyPopup",
    content: [{
        type: "fields",
        fieldInfos: [
            // fields
        ]
    }],
    expressionInfos: [{
        name: "customer",
        title: "Customer",
        expression: "IIf($feature.customer == null, 'none', 'table-row');"
    }]
});
```

I would like to hide a table row based on a value.  Any easy way to do this?  The above expression did not hide the row.

Comment: `feature.customer ? table-row : null`

Comment: Martin thank you for the comment.  Do you have a working example for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will not be able to hide the row by twinkling the value. Remember that no value is a value (or something).

If you want to hide the row, you need to hide the correspondant field info. Now to do that you also need to know the value to make the decision. Luckily the view popup has the event `selectedFeature` when that occurs.

Here I take the code from this ESRI's example [ArcGIS JS Example - Popup custom action](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-custom-action/), and add a condition to hide any row that the feature has no value for it related field.

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>
        Custom popup actions per feature attribute | Sample | ArcGIS Maps SDK for
        JavaScript 4.26
    </title>

    <style>
        body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #viewDiv {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
        }
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.26/"></script>

    <script>
        require(["esri/Map", "esri/views/MapView", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer"], (
            Map,
            MapView,
            FeatureLayer
        ) => {
            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "streets-navigation-vector"
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                center: [-101.94981250000075, 41.20977753557709],
                zoom: 5
            });

            /********************
             * Add feature layer
             ********************/
            // sampling of breweries
            const featureLayer = new FeatureLayer({
                url: "https://services.arcgis.com/V6ZHFr6zdgNZuVG0/arcgis/rest/services/OpenBeerDB/FeatureServer/0",
                popupTemplate: {
                    title: "{name}",
                    lastEditInfoEnabled: false,
                    actions: [
                        {
                            id: "find-brewery",
                            image:
                                "https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/popup-custom-action/live/beer.png",
                            title: "Brewery Info"
                        }
                    ],
                    content: [
                        {
                            type: "fields",
                            fieldInfos: [
                                {
                                    fieldName: "name"
                                },
                                {
                                    fieldName: "address1",
                                    label: "address"
                                },
                                {
                                    fieldName: "city"
                                },
                                {
                                    fieldName: "state"
                                },
                                {
                                    fieldName: "phone"
                                },
                                {
                                    fieldName: "website"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            });

            map.add(featureLayer);

            view.when(() => {
                // Watch for when features are selected
                view.popup.watch("selectedFeature", (graphic) => {
                    if (graphic) {
                        // Set the action's visible property to true if the 'website' field value is not null, otherwise set it to false
                        const graphicTemplate = graphic.getEffectivePopupTemplate();
                        graphicTemplate.actions.items[0].visible = !!graphic.attributes.website;
                        
                        // -- KEY PART TO HIDE A ROW IF NO VALUE
                        for(const fi of graphicTemplate.content[0].fieldInfos) {
                            fi.visible = !!graphic.attributes[fi.fieldName];
                        }
                        // -- END

                    }
                });

                const popup = view.popup;
                popup.viewModel.on("trigger-action", (event) => {
                    if (event.action.id === "find-brewery") {
                        const attributes = popup.viewModel.selectedFeature.attributes;
                        // Get the 'website' field attribute
                        const info = attributes.website;
                        // Make sure the 'website' field value is not null
                        if (info) {
                            // Open up a new browser using the URL value in the 'website' field
                            window.open(info.trim());
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body class="light">
    <div id="viewDiv" class="esri-widget"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Cabesuon that is exactly what I was looking for.  But unfortunately, it looks like it has an arcgis issue, once you set the field not visible, it removes the atttribute from the attributes collection and no longer displays the field in the popup for any other features.  I tested it with latest arcgis javacript api and found this issue.  I am trying to see if maybe there is a way I can re-add the fields by refreshing the attributes somehow but could not find a way to do this yet.

Comment: Cabesuon, I found the issue!  It is fixed by adding:   outFields : ['*']   to the feature layer.  If you add to above it will also fix the issue in your example.  Thank you again, I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Hi Cabesuon, I am having a very similar issue now but in this case I need to use GraphicsLayer.  Would you be able to take a look at it please: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76814243